# Should I show none AJAX versions of my page to googlebot?

Tags: ajax, seo, search-engine, googlebot

I have a site, lets say has a paged lists of products.

The pagination is AJAX based, it degrades 100% without JavaScript.

With JavaScript Turned on or off this Url will show the same content. (page 4 of my list of products) the same applies for any filter and ordering filters.

```
~/products/list/4  { 4 = page number }
```

When googlebot lands on page 1 of my products it won't be able to page through the products because it is AJAX based pagination. So if I turn off the AJAX Pagination and fall back to "server side" pagination if the useragent == googlebot then it can index all my Urls which will have the same content as an AJAX enable page.

I have read about using `#!` but my site does has the same functioallity my urls are the same with or withour JS enabled.

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Please, do not show a diferent content if is Googlebot, because it may be considered black hat SEO. The best way to do define witch version you prefer is to use **[canonical metatag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_link_element)**.

If you do not know, please also read this: **[Making AJAX Applications Crawlable](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/)**